# VB 6.0 Splitting Function

Tags: vb6

RE: Splitting function [ VB 6.0 ]

From this:  in Tex1  I have:  "" Number space Number space Number ""

1 2 3

2 3 4

5 6 7

8 9 9

9 8 7..... and so..and so...

Using this splitting function code I manipulate the data getting this:

1 2

2 3

5 6

8 9       and later the second column

2 3

3 4

6 7

9 9 etc...

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim Lines() As String
    Lines = Split(Text1.Text, vbNewLine)
    Dim a As Long
    For a = LBound(Lines) To UBound(Lines)
        Lines(a) = Left$(Lines(a), 3&)  ''  or Mid$
    Next
    Text2.Text = Join(Lines, vbNewLine)
End Sub`
```

This works perfectly.
I stumble on getting the  "" First number space Last number: ""

1 3

2 4

5 7 etc....

Any suggestion to achieve this would be appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function again in your loop instead of Mid:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim Lines() As String
    Lines = Split(Text1.Text, vbNewLine)
    
    Dim Line() As String
    Dim sOutput As String
    
    Dim a As Long
    For a = LBound(Lines) To UBound(Lines) - 1
        Line = Split(Lines(a), " ")
        sOutput = sOutput & Line(0) & " " & Line(2) & vbCrLf ' First and last are index 0 and 2
    Next
    
    Text2.Text = sOutput

End Sub
```

If you want 1st & 2nd, you use:

```
sOutput = sOutput & Line(0) & " " & Line(1) & vbCrLf
```

If you want 2nd & 3rd, you use:

```
sOutput = sOutput & Line(1) & " " & Line(2) & vbCrLf
```

Comment: Wonderful !   This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks with appreciation.

Comment: A quick question
Following your suggestion, exmp : having 1000 lines in the textbox 
but I want to deal  only with the last 200 lines. What is the best way to 
split, but going only from the bottom ( last ) to the top ( first ) in this order ?

Comment: @rpmax please mark the answer as accepted. Regarding your follow up question, you can simply adjust your `For` loop counter to `For a = UBound(Lines) - 201 To UBound(Lines) - 1`. You should check that  `UBound(Lines) >= 200` before.

Comment: Done, New here, learning procedures. Many Thanks ( again )

Comment: To reverse the order, use `For a = UBound(Lines) - 1 To UBound(Lines) - 201 Step -1`.